# triggered state of obedience

Tags: cognitive-psychology, decision-making

I wanted to know whether there are known cases of people who unwillingly enter a state of obedience due to specific external triggers. Is this considered normal, and if not, are there known treatments?

Comment: Closely related: [Obey any command given suddenly, as in the Jumping Frenchmen of Maine](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/353/4086). Hypnosis would count for your purposes, right?

Comment: The title there is related, but the examples given there are vague. As to hypnosis - this is a state where the subject follows the hypnotist's suggestions. Exactly the behavior we want to get rid of.

Comment: It would most likely happen only after serious abuse and only in response to the abuser. There would not be an on-off switch. Stockholm Syndrome is one example of a similar problem. Your research can start there.

Comment: Many thanks, medica!
What if someone other than the abuser does something that resembles the abuser (e.g. gesture, phrase, outfit) - do you think this might trigger the state of obedience?

Comment: Not predictably, no, and not with every abuse case. I would say that is more of a television trope.